# RDF for software libraries?

Tags: shared-libraries, rdf, owl, semantic-web, n-triples

Are there RDF schemas, ontologies for software libraries? Let's say I'm a Lisp programmer familiar with quicklisp. Or I'm a C programmer using numerical packages. Or a MS programmer using DLLs. Has any software libraries like these been "semantic webbed" with RDF triples? If not, where might I start? I'm guessing there exist XML or JSON data management for libraries, correct?

Comment: Check e.g. http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/swo

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully get your question though: are you looking for a catalogue of ontologies with their type (subject matter) given? If so, try https://lov.linkeddata.es/ for a list of vocabularies (ontologies) that you can search through. The search loos at individual terms within the vocabs so any hits for terms you enter might indicate a vocab of interest.